# multiple series in Highcharter R stacked barchart

Tags: r, highcharts

After going through the highcharter package documentation, visiting JBKunst his website, and looking into list.parse2(), I still can not solve the problem. Problem is as follows: Looking to chart multiple series from a data.frame into a stacked barchart, series can be anywhere from 10 - 30 series. For now the series have been defined as below, but clearly there has to be an easier way, for example passing a list or melted data.frame to the function hc_series similar as what can be done with ggplot2.

Below the code with dummy data

```
mydata <- data.frame(A=runif(1:10),
               B=runif(1:10),
               C=runif(1:10))

highchart() %>% 
hc_chart(type = "column") %>% 
hc_title(text = "MyGraph") %>% 
hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Weights")) %>% 
hc_plotOptions(column = list(
   dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE),
   stacking = "normal",
   enableMouseTracking = FALSE)
   ) %>% 
hc_series(list(name="A",data=mydata$A),
        list(name="B",data=mydata$B),
        list(name="C",data=mydata$C))
```

Which produces this chart: 
[image]

Comment: how do I add extra label/tag to A B C on the X axis to indicate what those A,B,C represent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

a good approach to add multiples series in my opinion is use `hc_add_series_list` (oc you can use a for loop) which need a list of series (a series is for example `list(name="A",data=mydata$A)`.

As you said, you need to melt/gather the data, you can use `tidyr` package:

```
mynewdata <- gather(mydata)
```

Then you'll need to group the data by `key` argument to create the data for each `key`/series. Here you can use `dplyr` package:

```
mynewdata2 <- mynewdata %>%
  # we change the key to name to have the label in the legend
  group_by(name = key) %>%  
  # the data in this case is simple, is just .$value column
  do(data = .$value)
```

This data frame will contain two columns and the 2nd colum will contain the ten values for each row.

Now you need this information in a list. So we need to parse using  `list.parse3` instad of `list.parse2` beacuse preserve names like `name` or `data`.

```
series <- list.parse3(mynewdata2)
```

So finally change:

```
hc_series(list(name="A",data=mydata$A),
    list(name="B",data=mydata$B),
    list(name="C",data=mydata$C))
```

by:

```
hc_add_series_list(series)
```

Hope this is clear.

Comment: hc_add_series_list() is in the development version on github?

Comment: Yes. I'm going to update the CRAN version the next week.

Comment: No longer works. This solution, I think, describes converting a tidy dataset to dataframes, then to a list, in order to import as hc_add_series(). It would be nice to get this to a single step.