# Stacked barchart in highcharter with molten data

Tags: r, highcharts, ggplot2

I am trying to plot frequency on a stacked barchart with the following code

```
x = data.frame(
Clinic = c('A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C'),
Doctor = c('Kooner','Halliday','Katz','Alizadeh','Patel','Baxter','Kooner','Halliday','Patel','Katz','Alizadeh','Baxter','Katz','Patel','Alizadeh'),
VisitDate = c('2014-06-01','2014-06-01','2014-06-15','2014-07-01','2014-07-01','2014-07-01','2014-07-01','2014-07-01','2014-07-01','2014-08-01','2014-08-01','2014-07-01','2014-08-01','2014-09-01','2014-08-01')
)


allDates = data.frame(VisitDate=c('2014-06-01','2014-06-15','2014-07-01','2014-07-15','2014-08-01','2014-08-15','2014-09-01'))

library(plyr)
visits = plyr::count(x[,c(1,3)])
visits1 = merge(allDates,visits, all.x = TRUE)

library(highcharter)
hc = highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Visits")) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = allDates$VisitDate) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(
    dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE),
    stacking = "normal",
    enableMouseTracking = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  hc_series(list(name="Clinic-A",data=merge(allDates,visits1[visits1$Clinic == "A", ], all.x = TRUE)[,3]),
            list(name="Clinic-B",data=merge(allDates,visits1[visits1$Clinic == "B", ], all.x = TRUE)[,3]),
            list(name="Clinic-C",data=merge(allDates,visits1[visits1$Clinic == "C", ], all.x = TRUE)[,3])
  )

hc
```

I can plot this with `ggplot` without much coercion. Is it possible to do this in the `highcharter` without too much coercion(for example the 4 merge statements). The answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38093229/multiple-series-in-highcharter-r-stacked-barchart) doesn't work for me.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot()+
  geom_bar(aes(y = freq, x = as.Date(VisitDate), fill = Clinic),data = visits, stat = "identity")+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.title = element_blank())+
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hchart`, used in dataframe is similar to `qplot`. `hchart` try to have the same behavior as `qplot`.

So, how about this?:

```
hchart(visits, "column", x = as.Date(VisitDate), y = freq, group = Clinic) %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(
    dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE),
    stacking = "normal",
    enableMouseTracking = TRUE)
  )
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Error: Objects of class/type data.frame are not supported by hchart (yet).

Comment: Keep your packages updated! ;) `install.packages("highcharter")`

Comment: I had just installed it for the first time a few days ago and tried installing it again. Somehow the MRAN only installs 0.3.0. even though they show the latest version on the repo page. I will try to download from CRAN.

Comment: Hi I updated my package but using hchart does not provide the date format I needed. I tried using `hc_xAxis(dateTimeLabelFormats = '%b \'%y')` but it messes up the date format even more.

Comment: Hi! this is other question ;). But you are close, `dateTimeLabelFormats` is the right argument, but you're using it wrong, you need to give a list with the formats  `hc_xAxis(dateTimeLabelFormats = list(month = "%b", year = "year %y", day = "etc"))` (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats and http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/datetimelabelformats/)

Comment: Thanks, I added a seaprate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40245096/highcharter-hc-axis-not-options) on this with example. I have one more [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40185121/displaying-datatable-in-highcharter-tooltip) out on highcharter. Thanks for your timely help.

Comment: Lastly, if the answer help to your question accept it to help other with the same doubt. Regards,