# Displaying datatable in highcharter tooltip

Tags: r, highcharts, dt

Using the first block of code in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182340/stacked-barchart-in-highcharter-with-molten-data) I want to create a tooltip that would display the list of doctors visiting a clinic on a particular day.I tried the following code which displays nothing

```
library(DT)    
tltp = DT:: datatable(data.frame(Doctors = x[x$Clinic=="{point.series}"&x$VisitDate == "{point.x}",2]))
hc%>%hc_tooltip(pointFormat = tltp)
```

I also tried using the `tooltip_table` which gives error

```
tltp = tooltip_table(x = NULL, y = x[x$Clinic=="{point.series}"&x$VisitDate == "{point.x}",2]
hc%>%hc_tooltip(pointFormat = tltp)

Error: unexpected symbol in:
"tltp = tooltip_table(x = NULL, y = x[x$Clinic=="{point.series}"&x$VisitDate == "{point.x}",2]
tltp"
```

Apologies I am not fluent in writing javascript.

Comment: This is not a easy excercise. First of all `tooltip_table` return a template to show in the tooltip, and use, it doesn't return the text in the tooltip itself. And the arguments `?tooltip_table`  `x` and `y` are stringts, not vectors or datatables elements. I will try to put some example to try to explain this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the official page recommend, to use highcharter is good alternative read how highchartsjs works. So, see this example with a simple custom tooltip.

```
hc <- hchart(visits, "column", x = as.Date(VisitDate), y = freq, group = Clinic) %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(
    dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE),
    stacking = "normal",
    enableMouseTracking = TRUE)
  )
```

Adding the simple tooltip using the column names: `Clinic` and `freq`

```
hc %>% 
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "this is and clinic {point.Clinic} and freq {point.freq}")
```

The `tooltip_table` function is to make tables in the tooltip:

```
tt <- tooltip_table(c("Clinic", "Freq"), c("{point.series.name}", "{point.y}"))

hc %>% 
   hc_tooltip(pointFormat = tt, useHTML = TRUE)
```

If you need other data to show in the tooltip you can create the columun:

```
visits$doctors <- sample(letters, size = nrow(visits))
```

And then create the chart again (using the new data) and use this column in the tooltip:

```
hchart(visits, "column", x = as.Date(VisitDate), y = freq, group = Clinic) %>% 
  hc_plotOptions(column = list(
    dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE),
    stacking = "normal",
    enableMouseTracking = TRUE)
  ) %>% 
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "Here is the doctor {point.doctors}")
```

Comment: Thanks. That got my juices flowing. I can tweak your reply to get what I want.

Comment: Glad to help @earthlink

Comment: This works like a charm with `hchart` how would this work with `highchart` and `hc_add_series`?

Comment: You need to add the data as a list, so it will be `hc_add_series(data = list_parse(visits))`