# highcharter hc_axis not working correctly

Tags: r, highcharts

Follow up on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182340/stacked-barchart-in-highcharter-with-molten-data/40184022?noredirect=1#comment67751544_40184022) I am not able to get the x-axis labels in correct format using the code below.

```
hchart(visits, "column", x = as.Date(VisitDate), y = freq, group = Clinic) %>% 
   hc_xAxis(categories = allDates$VisitDate, title = list(text = 'Deadline'), type = 'datetime', dateTimeLabelFormats = list(month = "%b", year = "%y")) %>%
   hc_plotOptions(column = list(
     dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE),
     stacking = "normal",
     enableMouseTracking = TRUE)
   )
```

The resulting chart below has labels all messed up.

[image]

Also is it possible to specify interval as in 1 month, 15 days etc.

Comment: @jbkunst bumping this up

Comment: Hi @earthlink, Always it's better try searching in SO using the highcharts tag http://stackoverflow.com/tags/highcharts/info, then if you find a solution you can implement in highcharter https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/highcharter/vignettes/replicating-highcharts-demos.html

Comment: If yours data x is in milliseconds and represents date you should use `datetime` [type](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.type) axis - `hc_xAxis(type = "datetime")`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
hchart(visits, "column", hcaes(x = VisitDate, y = freq, group = Clinic)) %>% 
hc_xAxis(categories = allDates$VisitDate, title = list(text = 'Deadline'), type = 'datetime', dateTimeLabelFormats = list(month = "%b", year = "%y")) %>%
hc_plotOptions(column = list(
  dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE),
  stacking = "normal",
  enableMouseTracking = TRUE)
)
```

You need to add hcaes inside the hchart function. There are some nice examples here [Highcharter page](http://jkunst.com/highcharter/hchart.html)

Also Highchart prefer dates as timestamp to work the way you want, please check this answer [plotband.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53195409/highcharter-plotband-and-plotline-not-working/54709834#54709834)

I hope this help you. Have a nice day

edit1:

With this code you can add the select range to date you want,  however I think to this kind of data and chart it does not apply

```
hchart(visits, "column", hcaes(x = VisitDate, y = freq, group = Clinic))%>% 
hc_xAxis(categories = allDates$VisitDate, title = list(text = 'Deadline'), 
type = 'datetime', dateTimeLabelFormats = list(month = "%b", year = "%y")) 
 %>%
hc_plotOptions(column = list(
dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE),
stacking = "normal",
enableMouseTracking = TRUE)
 ) %>%
hc_rangeSelector(enabled = TRUE, buttons = list(
list(type = "all", text = "All"),
list(type = "month", count = 1, text = "1m"),
list(type = "day", count = 15, text = "15d"),
list(type = "day", count = 1, text = "1d")

), selected = 3)
```

[image: ex]